# Linker seems to ignore library and default to older version

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, shared-libraries, linker-errors

I've built a debug version of a shared library (OpenSSL) so I can step through a certain function with a debugger to better understand what's going on.

However, I'm having a difficult time actually linking with the debug version I've built.  For some reason, no matter what I do, the linker always ends up linking with the pre-installed system version, even though both versions are in the `usr/lib` directory, the soft-links are setup correctly (AFAIK), and I explicitly specify the debug lib on the command line when compiling.

So the **original** (system-installed) version of the shared library is:

```
>ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lh | grep libssl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   15 Sep 23  2016 libssl.so -> libssl.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 386K Sep 23  2016 libssl.so.1.0.0
```

And the **debug version**, which I compiled from source and configured as a shared library (using the fPIC flag for all object files), is:

```
 >ls /usr/lib/ -lh | grep libssl
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   29 Oct 19 11:31 libssldebug.so -> /usr/lib/libssldebug.so.1.0.2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 2.3M Oct 19 00:53 libssldebug.so.1.0.2
```

And it's the same with the other OpenSSL shared library, libcrypto.  I have a libcryptodebug.so.1.0.2 and a corresponding soft link in `/usr/lib`.

So, I try to build an executable and link against the debug shared lib like this:

```
 >g++ test.cpp -o test -std=c++14 -lssldebug -lcryptodebug -I openssl-1.0.2p/include/
```

And it compiles and links with no errors.

And YET... when I examine the executable with `ldd`, I see:

```
 >ldd test
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcaa39b000)
        libssl.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007ff717d37000)
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007ff71793b000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff717630000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff71732f000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff717119000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff716d6e000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff716b6a000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff717f98000)
```

So even though I explicitly linked with `-lssldebug`, and it compiled and linked with no errors, `ldd` still shows that the linker for some reason is linking with the non-debug version (`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0`).  I also tried running `ldconfig` and then recompiling/linking, but it still links with the old (non-debug) version.

So what is going on here?  What am I doing incorrectly that causes it to silently ignore the command line linker arguments and somehow just default to using the non-debug version (which has a completely *different* shared lib name!) somehow?

Comment: I don't think you did anything incorrectly. When you link to a shared library, it has embedded within its name , called SONAME.For openssl, it seems its debug version and the regular version has the same SONAME - and that is what the will be loaded at runtime.  i.e. the filename specified when you build the executable is not the one used at runtime.  The runtime linker just picks the first file in its searchpath that matches the SONAME it found at buildtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So even though I explicitly linked with -lssldebug, and it compiled and linked with no errors, ldd still shows that the linker for some reason is linking with the non-debug version (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0

You are mixing up static linking, and runtime loading (sometimes also called dynamic linking).

When you link with `g++ test.cpp ... -lssldebug ...`, you *are* linking with `libssldebug.so`, but (as `ldd` output tells you) that library is *not* used during runtime loading.

That is happening because `libssldebug.so` has a special dynamic tag `DT_SONAME`, which contains `"libssl.so.1.0.0"`, and the static linker records *that* name as the library to be loaded at runtime.

You can confirm this with:

```
readelf -d libssldebug.so | grep SONAME
```

You can examine the libraries that runtime loader will try to locate for a given executable with:

```
readelf -d ./test | grep NEEDED
```

Now that you understand the problem, how do you fix it?

One of two ways:

1. You could change the `SONAME` encoded in `libssldebug.so`, by relinking it with `-Wl,--soname=libssldebug.so.1.0.2`, and then relinking your `test` program. Use above `readelf` commands to verify that `SONAME` and `NEEDED` now contain `"libssldebug.so.1.0.2"`, and then `ldd` to verify that `libssldebug.so.1.0.2` is what the runtime loader will use.
2. Alternatively, it may be simpler to install `libssldebug.so` into a different directory (say `/tmp/libssldebug`), create a symlink `libssl.so.1.0.0 -> lissldebug.so` in that directory, and then ask the runtime loader to search this directory first with `g++ test.cpp ... -Wl,--rpath=/tmp/libssldebug`. With this solution, the executable will still search for `libssl.so.1.0.0`, but it will search for it in the `/tmp/libssldebug` directory *first*, and will find your copy.